# Task with specific predecessor and weekday - Project 2003

Tags: ms-project, constraints, ms-project-2003

I'm having trouble to schedule a task that has two date constraints:

1. It must happen 5 days after a precedessor task;
2. It must happen on Mondays.

I tried creating and using an specific calendar, that only has Mondays as work days, but it didn't work out when I inserted the 5 days of latency.

I'm using MS Project 2003.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What should happen if 5 days after the predecessor is actually a Tuesday? Does it slip to the following Monday or does the predecessor move back to allow it to start on Monday?

Comment: Hi Marv, it should slip to the next Monday. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the basis it should slip to the following Monday-

1. Add a milestone that depends on the predecessor with a lag of five days and add that milestone as a predecessor to your Monday task.
2. Then we have the issue of only starting on Monday in MS-Project 2003. I cannot recall, but I don't think 2003 had task calendars. If that is true you will need to create a resource calendar with only Monday as a working day, then create a small task (say 1 minute) and allocate to that task a resource that uses the only-Monday calendar. That forces your short task to start only on Monday. Then add that short task as a predecessor to your task, ensuring the resources assigned to that task work normal hours.

Point 1. will give you a minimum 5 day lag and point 2 will ensure the task has to start on a Monday.